# Application protocol for multiple devices on serial bus using the QP Framework

Tags: c, embedded, protocols, microcontroller, state-machine

I am currently looking at designing an application protocol using the QP Framework to talk to several devices using a serial bus like Canbus or LonWorks.

My idea was to develop an active object that subscribe to a set of events and translate to commands in the serial bus. And using two types of messages; peer to peer and broadcast. Peer to peer will be a send and response protocol. Button press from a display device will use a peer to peer command while adc value like temperature change will use a broadcast message.

The other solution propose by a colleague was to implement network variables similar to LonWorks. This requires a module to monitor variables change on one device, and performing polling read on the other. This requires knowledge of variable address of the other device in the bus during initialization.

I am leaning towards the first solution as this seems simpler and fit nicely to an event driven paradigm.

It will be great if someone can share some experience using QP framework for multiple devices, and type of application protocols used.

Ryan